# Spotify style responsive HTML5 template

Tags: css, html, themes, responsive-design

Im trying to build a 1 page site with an similar effect that is over spotify.com.
What I mean is that when you scroll down the background image changes and you still see elements stay over the last background in a very responsive and sleek way.
I've been searching around the web and different themes sites but couldn't really find a good one.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you looking is called `parallax` just search on google for `parallax plugins` or `parallax layout` and you will find many tutorials and plugins to make it much more easier

http://streetsmash.com/parallax-scrolling-plugins/

Comment: Managed to fix it... There was another div that had another 40px like I said... Thanks!!! really helped. May I ask why isn't it enough to have width:100% to have the background spread all over the page width?